# Understanding ".with" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Sorry this is probably a question that has been asked many times but as it regards what is a very common word in English it is pretty much impossible to google or search for it.

I have seen a few examples of Ruby code which looks like this:

```
EnquiryNotification.with(post: @post)
```

I'm trying to understand what the ".with" part does.  Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: This is not standard Ruby. It's most likely a method on an ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: Could be ActionMailer's [`with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized/ClassMethods.html#method-i-with) – that's a method to pass arguments to a mailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with` is a class method defined on the `EnquiryNotification` class (or one of its ancestors). The method is neither a keyword in the Ruby language nor is it a common method on classes shipped with Ruby itself or its standard library. As such, to find what this method does, you would likely have to consult the documentation of your chosen framework or application.

An example of a `with` method defined in a framework is [`Sequel::Dataset#with`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset:with) to add a CTE to the current query. The method is also available as a class method in Sequel model classes.

It could also be [part of ActionMailer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized/ClassMethods.html#method-i-with) as mentioned by Stefan in a comment above.

In any case though, make sure to consult the documentation of your chosen framework or library for details.

Comment: Ah, excellent. Many thanks for clarifying.  I thought it might be something new in the standard library  or some kind of new convention.